# What is the proper grok filter for my input?

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

My inputs lookes like:

```
"message" => "ERROR | [default task-55] my.package.className(Class.java:184) | - logstash-ERROR LOG\r",
```

my logstash configuration:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => {"message" => "%{WORD:logLevel} | %{WORD:task} %{WORD:callfrom} | - %{WORD:logmessage}"}
  }
}
```

my config xml file for log4j:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config">
    <Appenders>
        <File name="FILE" fileName="logfile.log" append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%p | [%t] %l | - %m%n"/>
        </File>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%p | [%t] %l | - %m%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.memorynotfound" level="debug"/>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

in kibana  i see that the logLevel is ok, i get the proper loglevel but the other words i cant get, what i missed from the filter?
Thanks for the helps!

***UPDATE***

I tried this code:

```
^(%{WORD:logLevel}) (%{TASK_PATTERN:task}) (%{CLASS:callfrom}) (%{GREEDYDATA:logmessage})$
```

with my custom pattern:

```
TASK_PATTERN (^\[.*\]$)
CLASS .*\)
```

but yet it is find just the loglevel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably possible to get even more specific than this, but according to [grokconstructor](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match), the following works:

```
%{WORD:level} \| \[%{WORD:task} %{NOTSPACE:callfrom}\] %{DATA:javaclass} \| - %{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

Remember, any unmatched characters such as `|` or `[` still need to be accounted for within the grok. Also, [these patterns](https://github.com/hpcugent/logstash-patterns/blob/master/files/grok-patterns) are a good reference point for what you can do for free.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Another little question is: Possible if i have multikine message i store it in the last "message" greedydata

Comment: You would need to use the `multiline` Logstash codec for the input to make sure that all of the expected lines are aggregated into a single log. This becomes very difficult when you have more than one Logstash instance handling documents behind a load balancer. However, yes, it is possible.